# Why won't my listview display?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to show a list of files using an ArrayAdapter into a ListView. As best as I can tell, the following should work but it is just leaving the ListView empty. I am not using a ListActivity.

Java

```
setContentView(R.layout.files);
findViewById(R.id.folder_use).setOnClickListener(this);
ListView view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.files);
File[] files = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
Log.d(TAG, files.toString());
view.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<File>(this, R.layout.file_row, files));
```

layout.files

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/local_instructions" android:text="@string/local_instructions"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/files" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@id/local_instructions"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/folder_use" android:text="@string/folder_use" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

layout.file_row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked hierarchyviewer to see what the measured size of your list is, how many children it has, and their sizes?

You're telling the ListView that its height should be `wrap_content` - this is meaningless for a ListView since its content can be arbitrarily large. You're also telling the list items to be `fill_parent` in height - this is meaningless for a container that can scroll, since the parent effectively has infinite height to fill.